# How do I search 2 or more strings inside another string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just started to teach myself Python, and I wanted to search an large array of strings for a couple of keywords. I tried using nested if statements but it's clunky and doesn't work.

Is there a easier way to do this? By the way, my array of strings is called `tmp`.

```
for i in range(0, len(idList)):
     for j in range(0, len(tmp)):
          if "apples" in tmp[j]: 
              if "bananas" in tmp[j]: 
                  if "peaches" in tmp[j]:
                      if "pears" in tmp[j]:
                          *Do something*
```

Comment: Consider doing a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) comparison,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(0, len(idList)):
     for j in range(0, len(tmp)):
          if all(s in tmp[j] for s in ("apples", "bananas", "peaches", "pears")):
               *Do something*
```

which makes it a bit shorter. The `all()` function allows you to check multiple conditions and this function evaluates to true when all conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote it sounds like you're trying to find *any* of the keywords in the `tmp` list, not *every* in one element. If that's the case, then your code should instead be

```
for i in range(0, len(idList)):
    for j in range(0, len(tmp)):
        if "apples" in tmp[j]:
            *Do something*
        elif "bananas" in tmp[j]:
            *Do something*
        elif "peaches" in tmp[j]:
            *Do something*
        elif "pears" in tmp[j]:
            *Do something*
```

so you would do something (different or the same) in each of those conditions. **If** "apples" is in the current element in the list, **then** do something. **Or**, if "bananas" is in the element, then do something else.

To shorten your code, take a look at [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return `False`. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def any(iterable):
>      for element in iterable:
>          if element:
>              return True
>      return False
> ```

This would make your code similar to Simeon's example, but replacing `all` for `any`.